# Removing views to prevent multiple instances

Tags: objective-c, xcode

This may sound complicated but I can answer any questions.  What I am trying to do in a very complex way is I have two views that I am trying to load on my Welcome Screen Main.  The first one I want loaded is PageOne's view "text1Title" so Page One method is called on awakeFromNib. Now when I hit the next button im telling it to hide the next button and run page one method again so that it will make the if statement valid and remove text1View and load page two.  The problem is when I load PageOne view again it creates two instances of the view and removeFromSuperview only gets rid of one.  How can i make this more simplified and have this work? thanks.

```
@implementation WelcomeScreenMain


    NSString *const text1Title      = @"WelcomeScreenText1";
    NSString *const text1Title2     = @"WelcomeScreenText2";


    - (void)awakeFromNib
    {   
        [self PageOne];
    }

    - (void) PageOne
    {
        //Page One

        WelcomeScreenText1* text1View =
        [[WelcomeScreenText1 alloc] initWithNibName:text1Title bundle:nil];
        // embed the current view
        [myTargetView addSubview: [text1View view]];
        // make sure we automatically resize the controller's view to the current window size
        [[text1View view] setFrame: [myTargetView bounds]]; 

        if (myButton.isHidden) {
            [[text1View view] removeFromSuperview];
            [self PageTwo];
        }


    }

    - (void) PageTwo
    {
        //Page Two

        WelcomeScreenText2* text2View =
        [[WelcomeScreenText2 alloc] initWithNibName:text1Title2 bundle:nil];
        // embed the current view to our host view
        [myTargetView addSubview: [text2View view]];
        // make sure we automatically resize the controller's view to the current window size
        [[text2View view] setFrame: [myTargetView bounds]];
    }

    -(IBAction)nextButton:(id)sender
    {

        myButton.hidden = YES;
        [self PageOne];

    }

    @end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove all the instances of PageOne view before you attempt to add it again.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{ 
   NSArray *subv = [NSArray arrayWithArray:myTargetView.subviews];
   for(NSView *view in subv)
   {
      if([view isKindOfClass:[WelcomeScreenText1 class]])
      {
         [view removeFromSuperview];
      }
   }
   [self PageOne];
}
```

You could add that snippet at the start of `PageOne` too. Up to you.

Note that the subview array is copied as you can't enumerate something you might mutate.

Irrelevant style issue is that normally obj-c methods start lowercase so `pageOne` not `PageOne`